# Composer unable to run post install script

Tags: bash, composer-php

I'm getting the following error when trying to run a bash script in Composer post install/update hooks:

```
> post-install.sh
sh: 1: post-install.sh: not found
Script post-install.sh handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error



  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output: sh: 1: post-install.sh: not found
```

**Original composer.json**

*Works but it's just annoying to update the post install/update commands to run in two places.*

```
{
  "require": {
    "twbs/bootstrap": "3.3.5"
    ...
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "mkdir -p _libraries",
      "cp -r vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist _libraries/bootstrap/",
      ...
      ...
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "mkdir -p _libraries",
      "cp -r vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist _libraries/bootstrap/",
      ...
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

According to the [Composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md):

> A script, in Composer's terms, can either be a PHP callback (defined
>   as a static method) or any command-line executable command.

So my `composer.json` should be able to work as such:

**Wanted composer.json**

```
{
  "require": {
    "twbs/bootstrap": "3.3.5"
    ...
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "post-install.sh"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "post-install.sh"
    ]
  }
}
```

**post-install.sh**

*Executable by everyone (`0775`) and located in the same directory as the composer.json*

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p _libraries
cp -r vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist _libraries/bootstrap/
...
...
```

Comment: did you make `post-install.sh` executable? (e.g. `chmod 0755 post-install.sh`) You say it is, but I just thought I would confirm. Also, how is it being executed by Composer? It is calling it by some `php` call?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes it's executable. The bash script is not being executed by Composer. (I'm not to sure what you're asking here)

Comment: How should composer find that script?

Comment: @hek2mgl I wouldn't be asking the question if I knew, but I assume it does so by putting the script in the same directory as `composer.phar` and `composer.json` and defining the script under `scripts` in `composer.json`...

Comment: Does it work when you use `sh post-install.sh` ? However, I guess it should be even `sh vendor/you/yourproject/post-install.sh`. Have no test setup by the hand

Comment: @hek2mgl Yes it does! Write an answer so I accept it :)

Comment: Ok, can do that. You used `vendor/you/yourproject/post-install.sh` ?

Comment: @hek2mgl No I've just changed `post-install.sh` to `bash post-install.sh`. It also works with `sh` instead of `bash`

Comment: Ok, in that case `./post-install.sh` should work too. Can you confirm that?

Comment: `./post-install.sh` doesn't work, I tried it earlier but forgot to include it in my question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33550138/composer-unable-to-run-post-install-script?noredirect=1#comment54886818_33550138) I suggested to use

```
bash post-install.sh
```

This seems working.

Answer (score 25):

Other way to achieve single task definition is [referencing scripts](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#referencing-scripts):

```
{
  "require": {
    "twbs/bootstrap": "3.3.5"
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "your-cmd": [
      "mkdir -p _libraries",
      "cp -r vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist _libraries/bootstrap/",
      ...
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "@your-cmd",
      ...
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "@your-cmd",
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```