# How can I install my bootstrap dependecies in my webroot folder by composer

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, composer-php

I want to use composer to install bootstrap in my cakephp project but when I use the composer command it's installed in my /vendor.

I want it in /webroot.

Comment: Composer is package manager for PHP not HTML/JS/CSS.  But if you want you can use composer script command for c/p to your other destinations. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41976303/1127933 . Again, for frontend development use tools like grunt, gulp, yarn, .. https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp

Comment: Use npm / yarn and webpack to build your assets and JS. Read the docs of these tools and use Google search, there are thousands of articles and tutorials.