# Add new environment variables to .env when installing a package

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, dotenv

In our company, several internal projects rely on the same copied code parts to handle connections to the same APIs (like: Google Suite, JIRA,...). To avoid copying the same code over and over again for new projects, I want to create Symfony packages that collect these API classes.

The tricky part: I'm looking for a way to add the neccessary env variables automatically to `.env`, just like [Symfony's recipe structure does it](https://github.com/symfony/recipes#env-configurator). But as these projects should only be used internally, pushing their recipe configuration to a public repository is a no-go for me. Adding a custom recipe server (like the one by [moay](https://github.com/moay/server-for-symfony-flex)) looks interesting to me, but needs additional configuration in each projects `composer.json`.

Is there any better way to resolve this, such that I could simply define the needed variables solely in my project, such that they get added to `.env` without any additional magic?

NB: anything that requires `symfony/flex` is fine, as this should be part of all new projects in our company

These are solutions I want to avoid:

- add configuration to bundles / packages itself, such that these configuration values are put under version control
- add configuration through any other command that is run **manually** after installing

Comment: what type of variables are you adding? Would they be more appropriate as configuration vars?

Comment: There's an [open issue](https://github.com/symfony/flex/issues/567) about allowing endpoint configuration globally. If it gets implemented you could just add it to the developer profiles.

Comment: @craigh the configuration consists of two variables, and like in my other projects, I want to use an env variable for this as these variables should not be put under source control

Comment: To resolve a similar problem we have a separate project which stores all configs. The deploying script knows where to connect to get configs. So during the deploying stage, it connects to the project, takes configs for a specific project, and replaces it in the project (this approach might be too complex if you have not too many projects).

Comment: @SergeiKarpov thanks for sharing your experience - but to be honest: this is once more a step that needs configuration per project (in terms of: run that special part to gather configuration), and that's what I'd love to avoid

Comment: Are you looking for option to auto populate the `.env` file on local too? If not, and you're using a deployment script on different environments, then Ansible could do some work as part of deployment. But if you're trying to do it on your local too, then would you consider using docker to run a server?

Comment: What do you mean by "on local"? `composer require`  is only run on developer machines, but I see no connection to Docker

Comment: @UrmatZhenaliev can you share more details about that "env configurator"? As far as I know, it only works with public recipes

Answer (score 2):

You can use composer events for this process. After the package is installed, you add it to the .env file with a symfony command.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md

[Composer unable to run post install script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33550138/composer-unable-to-run-post-install-script)

There is a sample in the symfony composer.json file.

```
...
"scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
        "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
        "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ]
},
...
```

After each update or installation, this command is run "post-update-cmd, post-install-cmd".

Comment: Can you share more details? Editing `composer.json` to add such configuration as scripts after the package itself was already required is something I want to avoid

Comment: Symfony flex uses the same logic. It adds the parameters required when installing the package to the .env file. You will do the same with composer events.

Comment: While installing your packages, you will add the parameters you want to the .env file with shell or php.

Comment: No, adding the parameters manually is a definite no-go, and that's not how Symfony's recipes work after all

Comment: For example, this is the configuration of Doctrine's bundles to add `DATABASE_URL` to your project: https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/1.6/manifest.json#L9 - no additional configuration in `composer.json` needed, no manual work needed, Flex does all the work for you

Comment: Flex is a composer plugin. It works after every package installed with Composer. https://github.com/symfony/flex/blob/7c48460b7be9284b226e78af96716d762c567916/src/Flex.php#L978

Comment: What you need to do is to set up the same logic for yourself.

Comment: I know about Flex, I've already written my own recipes for other purposes - that's why I've mentioned it in my initial post. Adding our own package of type `composer-plugin` might be a solution, but I'm still curious if there is any easier way

Answer (score -1):

In Symfony, the `.env` file is now committed into the repository. So It's not a good practice to put sensitive data on it.

A better solution is to create a file name `.env.local`. This file is not committed and it overrides all environnement value in `.env`

so you could have in `.env`

```
MY_SENSITIVE_DATA=mypersonalkey
```

and in your `.env.local`

```
MY_SENSITIVE_DATA=the_real_sensitive_data
```

source: https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#overriding-environment-values-via-env-local

Comment: I haven't talked about using sensitive configuration in these variables, I'm just looking for a way to put them in `.env` automatically on requiring the package